# How to disable return value optimization in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, return-value-optimization

Is it possible to disable RVO (return value optimization) in Visual Studio 2010? Setting optimization flag to `/Od` (turns off all optimizations) doesn't help. In g++ there exists flag `-fno-elide-constructors` which disables RVO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot. It is just that simple. RVO/NRVO is Standard, and your code should not depend on it not being present.

Comment: As far as I can tell RVO/NRVO is **not** the Standard (see C++0x standard, section 12.8. Copying and moving class objects, paragraph 32). The Standard simply allows such optimization (g++ and VisualStudio implements it). I have no problem with that. But it would be nice to have some switch to disable it. For educational purposes maybe. Thank you, it's much clearer now :)

Comment: @Goran: If the Standard explicitly allows it, then it is Standard.

Comment: Allow != require. As such it isn't part of the standard, it merely won't contradict the standard.

Comment: @Jorgen: If including it does not contradict the Standard, then it is Standard- i.e., you cannot ever write code that assumes that it is not included.

Comment: "If including it does not contradict the Standard, then it is Standard." I think it'd be more precise to say that "then it is allowed by the Standard.", and that does not necessarily mean that a compiler shouldn't provide a flag to turn it off. For instance I  wanted to turn it off for educational purposes.

Comment: It's not standard. Based on the `standard draft(N296) 12.8 Copying and moving class object -- 31.3`, `the copy/move ctor op can be omitted by ...` which is what we call RVO here. I think it's saying compiler is allowed compiler to do such optimization. But it's not mandatory. Thus whether compiler do RVO or not follows the standard anyway. Do I misunderstand the standard? Thanks.

Comment: @Puppy The issue here - i.e. what the question is possibly asking, and what I arrived at the question looking for - is that you *also* cannot ever write code that assumes that it **is** included, because it is Standard-compliant to not include it. Hence, a compiler which provides and respects an option to disable it is Standard-compliant with or without the option enabled. If I want to write portable code, I may want to test my code both with and without it enabled, to ensure that it will work with all Standard-compliant compilers. This is easiest with a compiler-provided flag to disable it.

Comment: @JamieS That's the only presented motivation that actually makes some sense. I might comment that it's tricky to do this with testing because the exact situations where a compiler implements RVO and friends may differ between compilers or versions, so the preferable option is to simply not write objects that have impure copy/move constructors. That being said, you may have legacy code, etc, which does not do this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try to define your variable as `volatile`, maybe solves your problem. If it does not, you should send come code...

Comment: +1; although this is just a random guess (and as such deserves downvotes) it is correct that `return my_volatile_variable;` does disable RVO. (C++11 §12.8/31 item 1.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I am curious why you thought of my answer as just a random guess. The "maybe" in my answer meant that I was not sure of this answer because I did not know what the real problem was. IMHO, this question is in the vein of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'd suppose that's the reason they downvoted you. (It's better to justify an answer involving `volatile`.)

Answer (score -2):

There is never any reason to disable this optimisation!  What are you trying to achieve?  It helps debug builds run faster without any bad side-effects at all.  It also ensures code dependent on RVO or NRVO works identically in debug and release.

Comment: I can think of one (at least to me) very important reason: education! How do you explain constructors, move/copy constructors, destructors in function calls to a student when compiler omits them!?! I'm very grateful for g++ for supporting such an option.

Comment: I have to disable it to understand the lifetime of a returned value, I can't understand it now because it doesn't create the temporary, just copies it straight in.

Comment: @Zebrafish If you're changing the lifetime of a returned value to understand the lifetime of a returned value, I don't think your understanding will be correct.

Comment: @Goran You're teaching them wrong because their understanding will suddenly cease to apply when they try to use it in the real world...