# How does RVO and rvalue returned by the function work?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, rvo

To understand the way how compiler selects constructor of a class, I wrote code following:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Widget
{
    Widget(Widget&& w){std::cout << "Move ctor" << std::endl;}
    Widget(void){std::cout << "Default ctor" << std::endl;}
    Widget(const Widget& w){std::cout << "Copy ctor" << std::endl;}
};

Widget make_widget(void) //helper function
{
    Widget w;
    return w;
}

int main(void)
{
    Widget w(make_widget());
}
```

According to item 25 of Effective Modern C++, compiler treats w as to be rvalue reference because of Return Value Optimization. So I expected `Widget w(make_widget())` calls move constructor. but it doesn't. Furthermove, it prints only

```
Default
```

So I have no idea which version of constructor was called.
Then I also tried to return rvalue explicitly. That is, `return std::move(w)`
.
Against my expectation considering above result, it correctly called move constructor, and printed

```
Default
Move
```

It seems I'm in the maze of rvalue. Please tell me what's going on there.

Comment: An important part you forgot, and that is closely related to [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), is [*copy elision*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision), which will explain your behavior.

Comment: You seem to be confused about what RVO is. RVO *removes* unnecessary calls to the move constructor.

Comment: Your text would be easier to read if you wouldn't call everything `w`…

Comment: Seemd I misunderstood the job of RVO. I'm now coming to know RVO and optimization gradually.

Answer (score 3):

> According to item 25 of Effective Modern C++, compiler treats `w` as to be rvalue reference because of Return Value Optimization.

No, I am sure the author didn't mean that.  RVO has no bearing on something being an rvalue reference or not. The `w` in both `make_widget` and `main` is an lvalue of type `Widget`.  If you have a variable of type `Widget&&`, its value category is lvalue (since it has an identity) and its type is rvalue reference.

The `Default` you see is due to `Widget w;` inside `make_widget()`.  Due to return value optimisation, the operation of copying this to the `w` in `main` is avoided, so you see nothing further. If you want to see the output without RVO, then pass `-fno-elide-constructors` to `g++` if you use it (disabling RVO with VC++ [isn't possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9941043/183120)), you would see

```
Default (first creation)
Move    (creation of temporary with the move ctor)
Move    (copying of temporary to the one in main)
```

When you change `return w` to `return std::move(w)`, the temporary created for returning is constructed with the rvalue, hence you see an additional *Move* in the output.

Comment: Does the "temporary" in context "creation of temporary with the move ctor" mean make_widget's return value?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks for noticing this; confusing, yes. Fixed now!

Comment: @darkspider The type of the [temporary](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4214153/183120) is the same as the function's return type, however, its value category is an rvalue since it doesn't have a name. An expression involving an rvalue which incurs an side effects on it is disallowed. It [can only be bound](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1565600/183120) to an rvalue reference or a const lvalue reference or copied to an lvalue.

Comment: I finally understand that thanks to (N)RVO, this code is processed as if w in make_widget is directly constructed in w in main. In this way, two moves, which appear when RVO is disabled, are eliminated, and only "Default" is printed. Considering this behavior, to keep its portability, writing constructors which have any side-effect is not promoted because the outcome can change depending on whether optimization is on or off. I hope I don't misunderstand your whole explanation.

Comment: @darkspider: One case where it's okay for constructors to have side effects is when those side effects are undone by the destructor. For example, with `std::shared_ptr`, the copy constructor has the side effect of incrementing the reference count of the stored object, and the destructor decrements it.